# How to find all references of sobject salesforce?

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, migration

I wanted migrate all pages, classes related to Opportunity to custom object, I tried querying the pages, and classes but there is no way to do so,  How can i find all references of standard opportunity?

Any suggestions/pointers would greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Force.com IDE/Eclipse.
You can search there for any sentence in project